# how can i access my hidden folders with "react-native-fs" after giving scoped storage permission for that folder in REACT NATIVE?

Tags: react-native, scoped-storage, react-native-fs

How can i access my hidden folders with "react-native-fs", without giving any permission except **scoped storage**